# I want Applescript to execute two commands at the same time

Tags: applescript

I want Applescript to execute two commands at the same time. One is "display dialog" and the other is "choose file".
Because of the results of this code running, I think he can do what I want

```
ignoring application responses
set canshu to 0
repeat 10 times
    set canshu to canshu + 1
    display dialog canshu
end repeat
end ignoring
```

But not.

```
ignoring application responses
choose file
display dialog "hallo"
end ignoring
```

That's what I wrote.
It does not execute "choose file" for me but directly executes "display dialog". Why is that? Is there any other method?

Answer (score 0):

o'reilly.com says regarding your problem:

> Within the [ignoring] block, *only Apple events sent to* ***other
>   applications*** are affected [=ignore responses].
>   Apple events sent to scripting additions, for example, ***are sent in the normal way***.

For your script (=> "System Events") ScriptEditor opening a choose-dialog-window is an "other application", but `display dialog` (or `display alert`) are considered Apple "events".

*(Btw: you may excempt parts of code in an ignoring-block by inserting it into a considering-block.)*